# Combine CSVs from Folder - Separate Function

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, business-intelligence

Hi I am new to Power BI and I am facing an issue.

I have a Folder of csv files which I have to import. The csv files has readings of a electronic device

[image]

I imported the csv folder and I got such a Screen

[image]

Then I tried to remove the unwanted columns

[image]

now I have a column that shows the sourse file that is in my case the csv file for **eg-MFT_RB1_2017-08-08_11-26-56.csv**

I am getting all the data i.e the combined data of over 100 csv file in one sigle table as shown above. I want to create diffrent tables for each csv files. I can do it manually by importing csv files seperately like this -

[image]

But when I am importing a folder I am getting a sigle combined table, I want to split the main table into tables=number of csv files and visualiye the output as above

(I got the above visualization by importing 6 csv one by one, which works perfect)

But when importing a complete folder I am getting one big table with all 100 csv combined and I want to create diffrent tables for diffrent csv like I did with the above visualization.

[image]

Also, I have over 100 csv files in the folder and if I add 50 more in the folder it should automatically create tables of those newly added csv files.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: May I ask why you want them all in separate tables? That sounds more cumbersome to me. If you use slicers or filters and put the file name column in the Legend box, you should be able to recreate an analogous visual.

Comment: I have a foldersv files and I want to compare for example the values of X(MS) to Y1 for all the csv's in the Folder. But when i am importing the file I am not able to do that because it gets combined and I even tried without combining them. It ist working. Could you suggest me a solution? As I am new to this I didnt understand completely what you ment sorry for that, could you simplify what you commented earlier about the slicer/filter?

Comment: From your last image which has all of the tables combined, try recreating the visual by putting `X(MS)` on the Axis, `y3` in the Values section, and `Source.Name` in the Legend box.

Comment: Hey hi.... Thank you for the support so far.... I got the visualization right.....

Comment: @AlexisOlson could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/48579564/9088652