# Visualisation in power BI

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

I had a trouble visualizing my output in Power BI. I have imported more than 1500 CSV files but every time I visualize it, it only shows 10 CSV files that are randomly selected among the 1500 CSV files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. How can I see all 1500 CSV visualization at once rather than just 10 CSSV?
2. If it's not possible then I wanted to know how is 10 CSV files selected out of 1500 CSV files? Is there any calculation involved or is it just a random selection that Power BI dose on its own?
3. In image4 I would like to know how the calculation is di=one for Average, Sum, Medium, and Maximum.

I have attached screenshots for reference. I tried using various filters but none has given me the desired output. In Image4 you can see that I can select the Sum Average Minimum Maximum and other filters....but neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI has a limit in the number of datapoints it can print on a graph. 
since january you have more options with the high density line charts.

you can read more about it here:
[high density sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-high-density-sampling)